# Can't see child component ref

Tags: vue.js

I have got 2 components, one component is a children of my main one.

For example:

```
<component-one>
    <template v-slot:slot-one>
        <component-two ref="example"></component-two>
    </template>
</component-one>
```

However, when I run `this.$refs` I can't see the `example` ref to that component. I have tried putting this within `this.$nextTick(() => {});`

Comment: It works perfectly for me, maybe try calling this.$refs in the mounted hook

Comment: Hmm, `mounted` doesn't appear to work either. I have just used events instead to pass the data I was after.